# Surjections from $ \mathbb N $ to itself where each image has an infinity of antecedents in $ \mathbb N $

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, functional-equations

I am interested in learning about more various examples of such functions, for example:

> Let's take an enumeration of $ \mathbb N ^ 2 $ and use a projection. Then we get a surjection from $ \mathbb N $ to itself, where each image has an infinity of antecedents in $ \mathbb N $.

I am curious if there is another type of such functions which is not using explicitly a mechanism of projection ($ \mathbb Q $ projected over $ \mathbb N $ for instance).

Comment: Map a power $a^k$ to $a$, map the rest to $0$.

Comment: @Crostul If I understand well, the reason why this is surjective is due to the fact that there is an infinity of prime numbers?

Comment: @Raito Both of the mentioned maps are not surjective.

Comment: $$f(n)= \mbox{ number of divisors of $n$}$$ should work. This is surjective as well.

Comment: @ctst Could you elaborate on why?

Comment: @Crostul That is a really nice one :-) I would suggest. Map a number with odd amount of digits to 0 and numbers with even amount of digits to the inverted sum of the two halves of the number, e.g. f(123456)=321+654. (I know, this is not nice, but it works)

Comment: @Raito what number would map to $4$ in your suggestion?

Comment: @Raito In the first one you will never get squares or your map will not be well-defined (assuming you don't fix k). The second one didn't map to numbers as $12=2*2*3$ with prime factors of power >1. So both are not surjective. The new one from Raito does the job and is really nice.

Comment: @ClementC. For which mapping?

Comment: "Map a power $a^k$ to $a$, map the rest to $0$."

Comment: @ClementC. None, all powers of 4 can be written as a power of 2, I guess.

Comment: So, not a surjection.

Comment: Here is another one: $$f(n)= \mbox{ number of digits $1$ appearing when you write $n$ in base $2$}$$

Answer (score 1):

While one can provide examples that don't explicitly address an enumeration of $ \mathbb N ^ 2 $ (as has been demonstrated in several comments above), nevertheless the following holds:

> For a function $ f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $, the following are equivalent:
>
> - for any $ m \in \mathbb N $, the preimage of $ \{ m \} $ under $ f $ is infinite;
> - there exists a bijective function $ e : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N ^ 2 $ such that $ f ( n ) = p \big( e ( n ) \big) $ for all $ n \in \mathbb N $, where $ p : \mathbb N ^ 2 \to \mathbb N $ is projection on the left coordinate.

So you're asking for nothing more than various examples of enumerations of $ \mathbb N ^ 2 $. One direction of the above equivalence is already noted by yourself. For the other direction, first define the function $ g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ with
$$ g ( n ) = \# \{ k < n | f ( k ) = f ( n ) \} $$
for all $ n \in \mathbb N $. Then define $ e : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N ^ 2 $ with
$$ e ( n ) = \big( f ( n ) , g ( n ) \big) $$
for all $ n \in \mathbb N $. The equation $ f ( n ) = p \big( e ( n ) \big) $ is an immediate consequence of the definition. If $ e ( n ) = e ( m ) $ for some $ n , m \in \mathbb N $, then by equality of left coordinates we get $ f ( n ) = f ( m ) $. Thus, if $ n < m $, we have $ \{ k < n | f ( k ) = f ( n ) \} \subset \{ k < m | f ( k ) = f ( m ) \} $ and $ g ( n ) < g ( m ) $. Similarly, if $ n > m $ we get $ g ( n ) > g ( m ) $. But by equality of the right coordinates, non of those cases can happen, and we must have $ n = m $. Therefore $ e $ is an injective function. To show that $ e $ is surjective, consider any $ m \in \mathbb N $. Since $ f ^ { - 1 } [ \{ m \} ] $ is infinite, we can define $ s : \mathbb N \to f ^ { - 1 } [ \{ m \} ] $ recursively with
$$ s ( i ) = \min \left( f ^ { - 1 } [ \{ m \} ] \setminus \{ s ( k ) | k < i \} \right) $$
for all $ i \in \mathbb N $. This way, $ s $ will be a bijection, and for any $ i \in \mathbb N $ we will have $ f \big( s ( i ) \big) = m $ and $ g \big( s ( i ) \big) = i $. Therefore, any pair $ ( m , i ) \in \mathbb N ^ 2 $ will be in the range of $ e $, and thus $ g $ is surjective, which completes the proof.